# Passing back variables created in a seperate thread? Android

Tags: android, web-services

I've been trying to use a JSON/Php web-service layer to access a MySQL DB via my android application and it works (from logs I can see the variables are holding the correct information) however when I try and pass the values back to the main thread they aren't getting stored?

```
public class ViewErrands extends Activity {
public String result = "";
InputStream is;
String json = "lol"; //set as lol to begin with, to be overwritten with string from DB
TextView tv; 
public int iss;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtv);
    sendPostRequest();
    tv.setText(json + "LOL" + iss); // the "lol" + "LOL" + 0 (should be 6) appear
}

public void sendPostRequest() {
    class runCode extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> { // seperate task

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idnum", "1"));

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.182/FYP/xshowall.php"); // PHP script to show all where id > POST
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "error in http conn " + e.toString());
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "error converting " + e.toString());
            }

            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    json = "id: " + json_data.getInt("ID") + ", title: " + json_data.getString("TITLE")
                            + ", content: " + json_data.getString("CONTENT");

                        );

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    runCode sendPostReqAsyncTask = new runCode();
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute();
}
```

Firstly, the json variable stays as 'lol' as if it was never changed when I try and copy in a value.
Is this something to do with the seperate processes? What can I do about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have parsed the data but never set to textview again.

You can do that in onPostExecute this method will be called on UI Thread so its safe. (Never try to set any view's property in doInBackground that will lead you to an exception)

```
public void sendPostRequest() {
    class runCode extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> { // seperate task

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idnum", "1"));

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.182/FYP/xshowall.php"); // PHP script to show all where id > POST
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "error in http conn " + e.toString());
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "error converting " + e.toString());
            }

            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    json = "id: " + json_data.getInt("ID") + ", title: " + json_data.getString("TITLE")
                            + ", content: " + json_data.getString("CONTENT");

                        );

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {   
            tv.setText(json);
      }
    }
    runCode sendPostReqAsyncTask = new runCode();
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute();
}
```